# How can I combine 2 txt files in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

So I have 5000 lines of numbers and I want to add 1000 lines from different txt file next to each number example:

1st file:

```
1312838
4134321
5436234
5245454
2465645
```

2nd file:

```
SUQVPZW
MADNODA
YZXQBLK
UTFSHXW
```

what I want:

```
1312838:SUQVPZW
1312838:MADNODA
1312838:YZXQBLK
1312838:UTFSHXW
4134321:SUQVPZW
4134321:MADNODA
4134321:YZXQBLK
4134321:UTFSHXW
etc..
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to understand your requirements: the resulting combination will be 5000 x 1000 = 5,000,000 lines?  I think if you are running Windows, a PowerShell script will be more suitable.    Displaying 5 million lines in Notepad++ will be really slow.

Comment: [Python Script - Plugin for Notepad++](https://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: That is not a job for Notepad++. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK to use PowerShell something like can do the work:

```
foreach ($a in (Get-Content c:\path\to\file1))
{
    foreach ($b in (Get-Content c:\path\to\file2))
    {
        $a,$b
    }
}
```

The problem is notepad++ is text editor and this is combination operation (where there is no t much place for editors).

This operation is named Cartesian Product and you should be careful with it because it can produce huge results (in sense of rows in file)

If you prefer `bash` here is one line command:

```
join -j 999999 -o 1.1,2.1 file1 file2 >outout_file
```

You can find the discussion (and answer) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47675223/2908599).

Be aware the complexity of these command is **O(N*M)** so with big sets you will have time or memory consumption.